# Reactjs app div onclick not working in IE 11 no function getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameter-passing, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I am working a project with reactJS as the main framework and using latest react hooks.
I am having a const function need to execute on a div item (child-component) on the left side, which consists of simple head and some padding kind of box.

**here is my code Function will get called in parent component**

```
    import React from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
    import classnames from 'classnames'
    import withStyles from 'react-jss'
    import * as R from 'ramda'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import CardItem from './card-item'

    const ParentComponent = ({
      classes
    }) => {
    const arrayData = [{name: "Jose", id: "1"}, {name: "Job", id: "2"}];
    const onSelect = (data) => () => {
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (<div> 
    {Array.map(item => 
     <CardItem 
      item={item}
      onclickFun={onSelect(item)}
     />,(arrayData))}
     </div>
     )
    }

    ParentComponent.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object
    }

    const styles = theme => ({
      card: {
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        minHeight: '150px',
        width: '100%',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: '1px',
      }

    })

    export default (withStyles(styles)(ParentComponent))
```

**The card Component code:**

```
            import React from 'react'
            import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
            import classnames from 'classnames'
            import withStyles from 'react-jss'
            import * as R from 'ramda'
            import { connect } from 'react-redux'

            const CardItem = ({
              classes,
              item,
              onclickFun
            }) => {
              return (
                <div className=[classes.card} onClick={onclickFun}>
                  <div className={classes.topContainer}>
                    {item.name}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            }

            CardItem.propTypes = {
              classes: PropTypes.object,
              item: PropTypes.object,
              onClick: PropTypes.func
            }

            const styles = theme => ({
              card: {
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                minHeight: '150px',
                width: '100%',
                borderStyle: 'solid',
                borderWidth: '1px',
              }

            })

            export default (withStyles(styles)(CardItem))
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `=> ()` in your onSelect function

Replace

```
const onSelect = (data) => () => {
    console.log(data)
}
```

With

```
const onSelect = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
}
```

Also when adding as prop to the cardItem you're calling the function as apposed  to passing the actual function like so

```
    onclickFun={() => {onSelect(item)}}
```

Replace

```
 <CardItem 
   item={item}
   onclickFun={onSelect(item)}
 />
```

With

```
 <CardItem 
    item={item}
    onclickFun={() => {onSelect(item)}}
 />
```

One more thing Array.map should be called on the array directly like so

```
{arrayData.map(item => 
 <CardItem 
  item={item}
  onclickFun={onSelect(item)}
 />)}
```

I created a working sandbox (I removed all styles to simplify it) 
[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-ives-fm3wk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Abhilash What's not working the onclick or the over all application?

Comment: @Abhilash I updated my answer and added a link to a sandbox

Comment: The onClick is not working in IE only. all other browsers it's working fine. The answer which you shared is kind of similar to my previous code even if (data) => () =>{}.

Comment: It's working for me on IE 11. Not sure what I may be doing differently than you.

Comment: Thanks for your support. In my case the child components are dynamic and not working any onClick on the div. But now I removed that component from my app and redesigned the page. Thanks for your support again.

Comment: Sure. Sorry I couldn't help you directly